How is CRC5 calculated in detail for a USB token?
How is CRC5 calculated in detail for a USB token?
ADDR = 0x01 and ENDP = 0x02 -->  CRC5 = 0x18
ADDR = 0x01 and ENDP = 0x01 -->  CRC5 = 0x0B
ADDR = 0x00 and ENDP = 0x00 -->  CRC5 = 0x02

This question was asked but no detailed answer.
How is crc5 calculated for a usb token?
All C source code I tried does not give the correct values.
All modulo calculations I tried do not work.
On page 198 USB specification: "... The generator polynomial is: G(X) = X^5 + X^2 + 1.
The binary bit pattern that represents this polynomial is 00101B ..."
But it must be: 100101.
The more I try to find out, the more questions I get and more inconsistencies I discover.
How to get these CRC5 values?

This question is similar to: How is crc5 calculated for a usb token?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is not answered in detail.

Reference
The USB organisation has a PDF on how to calculate this. This includes a not-very-obvious reference Perl script for calculating the crc5.
https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/crcdes.pdf
Run on your examples, it gives the same answers as you expected.
$ ./crc5 10000000100 # addr 1, endp 2 want 0x18
00011
$ ./crc5 10000001000 # addr 1, endp 1 want 0x0b
11010
$ ./crc5 00000000000 # addr 0, endp 0 want 0x02
01000

Note that the input to this crc5 script is bit-reversed addr followed by bit-reversed endp; the result is also bit reversed.
NB, to get the bit pattern for a given polynomial, you always truncate the result to the number of bits of the order of the polynomial.  So for x5 + x2 + x0, you do indeed set bits 5, 2 and 0 but then you truncate to 5 bits.  The result is that you lose the highest order bit.
In C
Rewriting in C, we get the following function, intended to be called as res = crc5usb((endp << 7) | addr);  In this implementation we are shifting res rightwards (ie, towards LSB) and so the polynomial is bit-reversed (binary polynomial 00101 becomes 10100, ie 0x14) and the values are natural.
unsigned char crc5usb(unsigned short input)
{
        unsigned char res = 0x1f;
        unsigned char b;
        int i;

        for (i = 0;  i < 11;  ++i) {
                b = (input ^ res) & 1;
                input >>= 1;
                if (b) {
                        res = (res >> 1) ^ 0x14;        /* 10100 */
                } else {
                        res = (res >> 1);
                }
        }
        return res ^ 0x1f;
}

Tested with all 27+4 values for addr and endp, matches the USB.org perl code.
$ ./crc5usb 1 2
addr = 0x01, endp = 0x2: crc5usb(0x101) => 0x18
$ ./crc5usb 1 1
addr = 0x01, endp = 0x1: crc5usb(0x081) => 0x0b 
$ ./crc5usb 0 0
addr = 0x00, endp = 0x0: crc5usb(0x000) => 0x02 


Commentary
The difficulty with this algorithm, like all CRC functions, is that you must match: input construction and bit reversal or not, initial CRC value, direction of shifting data, direction of shifting ongoing CRC, bit pattern of polynomial and any bit reversal, any final inversion.  You can change these for convenient implementation so long as you change it in several places: for example, right shifting the CRC register requires bit reversal of the polynomial.
For illustration, here's a left-shifting version of the same which gives bit-reversed results.  Notice at the beginning of the loop we XOR the top bit (not the bottom), we shift it left (not right), and we use a natural (not reversed) polynomial.
unsigned char crc5usbrev(unsigned short input)
{
        unsigned char res = 0x1f;
        unsigned char b;
        int i;

        for (i = 0;  i < 11;  ++i) {
                b = (input ^ (res >> 4)) & 1;
                input >>= 1;
                if (b) {
                        res = (res << 1) ^ 0x5; /* 00101 */
                } else {
                        res = (res << 1);
                }
                res = res & 0x1f;
        }
        return res ^ 0x1f;
}

You can easily see it computes the identical function on the individual bits by considering how the polynomial is represented by the bits of res; and as they are in a reversed order, the result will be bit-reversed.
crc5usb                           crc5usbrev
   4     3     2     1     0         4     3     2     1     0   
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| X^0 | X^1 | X^2 | X^3 | X^4 |   | X^4 | X^3 | X^2 | X^1 | X^0 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
shifting >>>                      shifting <<<

You may care to look at CRC5-USB in this CRC catalogue.
(Code tested on GCC 11.4.0 and Perl v5.34.0 on Ubuntu 22.04)

Well, at least I confirmed the first case with pen and paper.

The ADDR field is a 7-bit number 1 = 0000001b
The ENDP field is a 4-bit number 2 = 0010b
The fields are sent LSB first so the bit string to send from left to right is "1000000-0100" with the dash just acting as a delimiter
The 5-bit CRC is initialized to all bits 1, so 5-bit number 0x1F or 11111b
The transmitted data bit is XORed with MSB of CRC register
If MSB is now 1, left shift CRC and XOR with polynomial 0x5 (00101b), else if MSB is now 0, just left shift CRC without XOR with polynomial
Repeat for each data bit
When all bits processed, CRC value is 0x1C (11100b)
Then invert CRC bits, result is 0x03 (00011b)
Then send out CRC LSB first : "11000" = 0x18


As a side note, I tried the second case and did not get the correct CRC5 you stated. The first may be accidentally correct.

While not a direct answer to your CRC-5 question, keep in mind that besides the polynomial used, both sender and receiver have to agree on:

The initial value for the CRC register
Should the CRC be complimented or not, before being appended to the message
The order in which the CRC bytes are appended to the message (which byte first)
Whether or not the bits within each byte of the message are reflected (reversed) or not.

Note that @JustMe hinted at these issues in his answer.
I have a spreadsheet from several years ago that I used to verify a CRC-16 algorithm.  I'll try to resurrect that and modify it for OPs CRC-5 case.

I converted the perl script to C in this pdf file
https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/crcdes.pdf
with
https://codingfleet.com/code-converter/perl/c/
It is programmed very inconvenient (lol) but shows exactly what is going on.
I have not yet been able to recognize classical polynomial division.
Many thanks to all for help !!! :-)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function to perform XOR operation on 5 elements
void xor5(char *x, char *y, char *results5) 
{
  int j;

  for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
  {
      if (x[j] == y[j]) 
      {
        results5[j] = '0';
      } 
      else 
      {
        results5[j] = '1';
      }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    // all values in LSB first notation
    // ADDR = 0x01 and ENDP = 0x02 -->  CRC5 = 0x18
    // char input[] = { '1','0','0','0','0','0','0',  '0','1','0','0' };

    // ADDR = 0x01 and ENDP = 0x01 -->  CRC5 = 0x0B
    char input[] = { '1','0','0','0','0','0','0',  '1','0','0','0', };

    // ADDR = 0x00 and ENDP = 0x00 -->  CRC5 = 0x02
    // char input[] = { '0','0','0','0','0','0','0',  '0','0','0','0', };


    char *st_data = input;
    char G[] = {'0', '0', '1', '0', '1'};
    char results5[5];
    char nextb;
    char *data = st_data;
    char hold[] = {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1'};
    int data_len = strlen(st_data);
    int i;

    if (data_len > 0) 
    {
        while (data_len > 0) 
        {
            nextb = *data++;
            data_len--;
            if (nextb != '0' && nextb != '1') 
            {
              continue;
            }
            
            if (nextb == hold[0]) 
            {
              memmove(hold, hold + 1, sizeof(hold) - sizeof(hold[0]));
              hold[4] = '0';
            } 
            else 
            {
              memmove(hold, hold + 1, sizeof(hold) - sizeof(hold[0]));
              hold[4] = '0';
              xor5(hold, G, results5);
              memcpy(hold, results5, sizeof(hold));
            }
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(hold) / sizeof(hold[0]); i++) 
    {
        if (hold[i] == '1') 
        {
          printf("0");
        } 
        else 
        {
          printf("1");
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}


It's doing the calculation textually on arrays of characters representing the bits. All the XORs are done as not-XOR, using == on two characters. Perl push is shift left, array grows by one, shift is shift right return last value; function xor is defined to return only bottom 5 bits.  You can compare against the C in my answer, but honestly it's a tricky piece of code to do something pretty simple.
